# Jenkins - Stream live logs on Custom Dashboard

Tags: java, html, reactjs, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a jenkins CE being used to run close to 4000 jobs. For users, we have exposed a Dashboard on top on Jenkins APIs. Until now for the log viewing, we had provided an href link to with a logs button for checking logs. When the user clicks on the button, the jenkins logs page pops up in an iFrame. Is there a way to stream live jenkins logs on the UI as plain text, instead of opening up jenkins UI?

As of now I am calling the api to fetch the build log which is static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this calling the jenkins api `{jenkinsUrl}/job/jobname/buildNo/consoleText`

The api is called on a scroll event from the UI which is built on reactJS. Also an option is provided for the user to select auto load which would call the same api every 2 seconds to stream the latest content of the log.